# Axiomatic intersection theory

Tags: intersection-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there an axiomatic intersection theory?

What I expect is something like:
An intersection theory is a functor from the category of schemes(or other spaces) to the category of algebras, with well-defined flat pullback and proper pushforward, and (maybe) projection formula or some other axioms.

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in the [bivariant theories](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ogcqYWkW_r0C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Fulton and MacPherson.